# Managing multiple variations of one project with partially shared code?

Tags: development-environment

Excuse the fact that I cannot properly put it into words!

If you (for example) have a premium and trial version of your code, is there an easy way to deliver the same code updates to the core functionality, but keep other parts of the code seperate? I don't think Git branches would do the trick.

(Preferably using Git(hub))

Excuse this weird question!
- Stijn

Comment: Trial versions of an app are usually the full app. However there's logic in place to only allow access to limited features or reduce access when the trial has expired. However without a specific example it's hard to offer accurate advice.

Comment: @TidyDev How do developers of such apps then manage to keep those small differences seperate, while keeping the base code the same?

Comment: You'll need to provide a specific example for others to offer a proper answer. But if you had a website with trial features, you could check the users permissions every time they made a request and only serve them content that they have permission to view.

Comment: @TidyDev for example, if you take an application like Discord. Web version + desktop version share a lot of the code, but desktop has a few options more (overlay, for example). The electron code is all packaged differently than a website'd be, so how would they efficiently manage this?